# Interpretation of posterior predictive distributions

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, interpretation, posterior, prediction-interval

QUESTION UPDATE due to the comments I have received so far.

The data, the example and the results below are fictitious, as I am interested with the correct interpretation of these results.

Suppose I study the relationship between the human weight and its height with a Bayesian linear model. Suppose I plot posterior predictive distributions like in the graph below.

[image]

jbowman below said that there are no distributions on the graph.

I thought that the red bars would represent 95% most credible predicted height values, for any given value of weight. **Can I name those posterior predictive distributions?**

Also, I asked whether I can say “there is a 95% probability that a person with a weight of 110 kg is taller than a person with a weight of 100 kg”? I am inferring this because the posterior predictive distributions for the weights of 110 and 100 kg do not overlap.

Doctor Milt below said that I cannot. My question: **why**? I explain my misunderstanding in the following way:

Suppose I want to predict the height of a person who is 110 kg.

A feature of Bayesian analysis is that we get an entire distribution of credible predicted values, not only a point estimate. To get the distribution of predicted values, I can randomly generate simulated data from the model using the parameter values at that step.  I can think of this by looking at the vertically plotted red bars.

Am I right about this reasoning?

If so, suppose again that I want to predict the height of a person who is 110 kg. The lowest height value that the model can generate for this weight value is above 1,5 meters, this is according to the red bar on the graph.

Now suppose again that I want to predict the height of a person who is 100 kg. The maximum height value that the model can generate for this weight value is below 1,5 meters, this is according to the red bar on the graph.

Seems like that the predicted height values for a 110 kg person are always gonna be higher than the predicted height values for a 100 kg person. **Because of this, why I cannot say that “there is a 95% probability that a person with a weight of 110 kg is taller than a person with a weight of 100 kg”?**

Comment: This graph doesn't show any type of distribution, I'm sorry to say, unless the distributions are uniform over the highlighted intervals.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I say “there is a 95% probability that a person with a weight of 110 kg is taller than a person with a weight of 100 kg”?

You can't, but if you have the posterior you can (in principle) obtain the distribution of the difference in height between these two people, so you can compute the probability that the heavier person is taller.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The possible answer might be is that the predictions of heights at specific weights include the uncertainty in the intercept:

****Pred110 = mcmcMat[,"beta0"] + 110 * mcmcMat[,"beta1"] # predicted ht at wt=110**

**pred100 = mcmcMat[,"beta0"] + 100 * mcmcMat[,"beta1"] # predicted ht at wt=100****

But when the difference of heights is calculated, the uncertainty in the intercept is cancelled out:

**Pred110m100 = ( mcmcMat[,"beta0"] + 110 * mcmcMat[,"beta1"] ) - (  mcmcMat[,"beta0"] + 100 * mcmcMat[,"beta1"] ) =
( 110 - 100 ) * mcmcMat[,"beta1"] # difference of predictions**

Thus, it seems like that when we talk about the uncertainty in a difference, it should depend only on the uncertainty of the slope, not on the intercept.